# capture value in ngValue attribute in the component of angular 4

Tags: angular

I am implementing an Angular 4 application.I need to capture the value of the selected dropdown in my component. In this case I need to get the value of policyType.id which is assigned to the [ngValue] attribute in the html to the component. How do I achieve that ?

html

```
 <div class="only-ie">
          <select class="select-wrapper" [(ngModel)]="editableLob.coveragePolicyTypeId" (change)="coveragePolicyTypeChanged($event)"
            name="policyType" required tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.TITLETOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
            <option disabled="disabled" [ngValue]="defaultPolicyType">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.SELECT'|translate}}</option>
            <option class="theme--option--default" *ngFor="let policyType of policyTypes" [ngValue]="policyType.id">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.'+policyType.name|uppercase|translate}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Component

```
coveragePolicyTypeChanged($event) {
    this.updateCedingComission(this.showCededComission && this.editableLob.isCededCommision);


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use ngValue if you want the value to be an object.

Bind the value as `[value]="policyType.id"` for simple values. You should be able to get your value from `this.editableLob.coveragePolicyTypeId`